# XML POST calls from iOS application

Tags: .net, ios, xml, web-services, post

One of my client has backend server without any webservices but my iOS application is suppose to get/post data to services. How can i do that in absence of web services? They have .NET SPX type of calls.

Anyone suggest a way out to get/post data in such a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they running a website (iis, apache) on their backend server?  and is it exposed to the internet?  If they have a website,  you might be able to http post/get directly to the pages on the website, provided that they are not protected by some form of security.

Comment: Yes they are running the backend server and website is already exposed to internet but now they like to develop an iOS native application but use the same services. Now this site is security enabled so i am not sure if i'll be directly use post/get. Pardon my little knowledge of this side but how about using XMLRPC if it can be used?

Comment: I would think that XML RPC would be a very viable option.  Basically XML-RPC is very similar to a regular web service in that XML is passed in as the request, and returned as the response,  really the only difference is that you are not obligated to adhere to the SOAP standard, provide WSDL, etc when using XML RPC.